# React conditionally returning a mapped bootstrap element based on array length

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, carousel, react-bootstrap, ternary

I'm creating a project page, where I'm mapping a React Bootstrap Image Carousel for each project from an array of images.  That's working fine, but the problem is, if there's only one image in the array, I'd like the "next" and "previous" arrows not to appear.  So I tried conditionally returning the Carousel.Item when the array length is greater than 1, and a regular image otherwise (not inside Carousel.Item tags).  But because it's still within the Carousel itself, it thinks it's another Carousel slide and the arrows appear.  I suspect I have the ternary statement laid out incorrectly, but every other configuration I've tried has resulted in an "Unexpected Token" error.

```html
<Carousel>
  {imageArray.map((image, id) => { 
    return imageArray.length > 1 ?

  <Carousel.Item key={image.id}>
    <div className='project-image'>
      <img src={ image} style={{width: "80%"}} alt={title.rendered}/>
    </div>
  </Carousel.Item>
  
  :
  
  <div className='project-image'>
    <img src={ imgUrl} style={{width: "80%"}}alt={title.rendered}/>
  </div>
  })}
</Carousel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the ternary operator above the `Carousel` and return a carousel if your array is longer than one and a static image otherwise.

*In my opinion it makes more sense in general as you are currently checking the length of the array for every item iteration. However you really only need to do it once.*

**Here is the updated code:**

```
{imageArray.length > 1 ?
  <Carousel>
     {imageArray.map((image, id) => (     
       <Carousel.Item key={image.id}>
         <div className='project-image'>
           <img src={ image} style={{width: "80%"}} alt={title.rendered}/>
         </div>
       </Carousel.Item>
     ))}
   </Carousel>
  :
  <div className='project-image'>
    <img src={ imgUrl} style={{width: "80%"}}alt={title.rendered}/>
  </div>
}
```

You might have to changes the styles of the `.project-image` div a bit to accommodate for the fact that it is no longer wrapped by a `Carousel`.

Comment: Perfect, that did it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try storing your Carousel mapping functionality outside in a const then check the length to conditionally change it's value then inject the value {images}.

```
const carousel = imageArray.map((image, id) => {
<Carousel>
  <Carousel.Item key={image.id}>
    <div className='project-image'>
      <img src={ image} style={{width: "80%"}} alt={title.rendered}/>
    </div>
  </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
}

const default = (<div className='project-image'>
    <img src={ imgUrl} style={{width: "80%"}}alt={title.rendered}/>
  </div>)

const images = imageArray.length > 1 ? carousel : default 


return (
{images} 
)
```

Comment: I see a few problems with this solution... First of: `default` is a reserved keyword and can not be used as a variable name. Second: Doing it like this means that the map function will **always** be called even if the computed array is not needed. To be fair the array only contains <= 1 item if it is not needed. But it is something than can just be avoided easily. However the biggest problem ist that you **do not return a React Node**. Your return statement actually returns an object `{image: image}`. Using `return image` would work.